# Ray Tracing Bounding Volume Hierarchies nodes

Tags: raytracing, rendering, optimisation, bounding-volume-hierarchy, optimization

I'm new to computer graphics programming so I apologize in advance if my question is stupid.

I'm trying to implement a BVH for my ray tracer and I looked at some lectures explaining BVH. They all mention that a BVH takes in primitives which are then divided until they end up as nodes of the tree, but when I looked at scratch-pixel, they were talking about having the meshes as nodes. I'm a bit confused here because I'm not sure exactly which is the right way of doing it. Should the nodes contain the meshes as a whole or should I just feed the BVH construction algorithm the primitive triangles (ignoring the fact that they are a part of a mesh by just grouping them into a list/array of primitives)?

Comment: RE *"talking about having the meshes as nodes."* that seems very unlikely *unless* each mesh is trivial, say, only a few triangles.   Testing rays against triangles is *much* more expensive than against an AABB or sphere and, since most rays will typically miss all but a handful of triangles, in a given mesh, it would be quite inefficient.

Comment: I would go with a target of a handful of triangles, say 6-8 triangles per BVH node. There will be duplicate triangles though if you hit a leaf node and didn't hit any triangles and then move to a neighbouring node, the same triangle can exist in both nodes (The number of shared triangles typically increases the less triangles per node you opted for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bounding Volumes

A bounding volume is for example an Axis-Aligned Bounding-Box (AABB), a generaal Bounding-Box not aligned with the major axes or a Bounding-Sphere. They differ in

- how much memory they take (e.g. a sphere takes only 4 floats, AABB 6 floats)
- how good they enclose the object's geometry
- how fast are the related computations (mainly intersection tests).

You will find an extensive overview at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume).

## Hierarchy of volumes

So in the hierarchy of bounding volumes, instead of whole meshes you will store only their bounding volumes. You choose a single type, e.g. a bounding sphere, and will use it to build the whole BVH. At the bottom level each bounding volume will probably enclose only a single object. You will build the hierarchy up by enclosing pairs or smaller groups of volumes in a larger volume.

So using spheres you would enclose each object into a bounding sphere at first. Then at the higher levels of the hierarchy, you would always create a new sphere enclosing a few spheres from the previous level which are close to each other. You proceed until a single root sphere encloses all 3D objects in your scene.

There are different [strategies to create BVH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy). But all have in common that complex structures like triangle meshes are hierarchically clustered using very simple entities.